# ChromeWebDriver- Dropdown menu- "United" is being passed through, not "United States", web form defaults to United Arab Emirates

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a java file that inserts a value into a specified xpath.  When it comes to a text box in a web form, ie-Address, it passes the whole string, ie- 101 Test Drive.

However, when it comes to a dropdown menu, it does not send the values following a space after the first word.  For example, when trying to pick "United States" it picks "United Arab Emirates".  I imagine it is only sending "United" and therefore defaults to the first options- U. A. E.

When trying to pick "Virgin Islands, U.S." it picks "Virgin Islands, Britain".

This was working a week ago.  Perhaps it is an issue with the latest ChromeDriver update?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Share code with us...

Answer (score 0):

Since we have no code, i cannot tell you what the actual problem is, but i could offer you an alternative.

Try using the `value` attribute instead.

```
new Select(By.cssSelector("select#country")).selectOptionByValue("usa");
new Select(By.cssSelector("select#country")).selectOptionByValue("uae");
```

Comment: Apologies, the code is `driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).sendKeys("UNITED STATES"); `